# QGIS Gazetteer Search/ Connection to SQL Server

Tags: qgis, sql-server, gazetteer

Is there anyway to connect an Microsoft SQL Server Spatial Dataset to QGIS (2.14) to enable a Gazetteer search, similar to the Gazetteer search function in Cadcorp?